# How to convert date format to milliseconds?

Tags: java, android

How to get the millisecond time from date? I have the following code.

```
Date beginupd = new Date(cursor1.getLong(1));
```

This variable beginupd contains the format

> Wed Oct 12 11:55:03 GMT+05:30 2011

Now how to convert this format to the millisecond time in Long datatype?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
long millisecond = beginupd.getTime();
```

[`Date.getTime()` JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) states:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Date object.

Comment: Wonderful! Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 13):

```
date.setTime(milliseconds);
```

this is for set milliseconds in date

```
long milli = date.getTime();
```

This is for get time in milliseconds.

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 11):

You could use

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(beginupd);
long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Works, and Calendar is more intuitive than Date.

Comment: Constructing a `Calendar`, setting the `Date` and then requesting it back using `getTimeInMillis()` is simpler than calling `Date.getTime()`?

Comment: I think @flash meant `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.set(2011,9,12,5,42,0); long ms = cal.getTimeInMillis();` is more intuitive than using old `Date` API even if his answer is less simple.

Answer (score 1):

`beginupd.getTime()` will give you time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT till the time you have specified in `Date` object