# how to get a formatted date as milliseconds?

Tags: java, android, date, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have a formatted date from sqllite database, to use this in a graph view I need to format it in a long number.

The format is:

2012-07-11 10:55:21

how can I convert it to milliseconds?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735705/how-to-convert-date-format-to-milliseconds

Comment: I need to format it from string, but the link shows how to convert from date type value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert the string into a Date object using this code:-

`Date d = DateFormat.parse(String s)`

And then convert it into milliseconds by using the inbuilt method

`long millisec = d.getTime();`

Answer (score 6):

Use `date.getTime()`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setLenient(false);


String oldTime = "2012-07-11 10:55:21";
Date oldDate = formatter.parse(oldTime);
long oldMillis = oldDate.getTime();
```

Comment: This gives a parse exception, instead use this format:                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.util.*;


public class ConvertDateIntoMilliSecondsExample{

public static void main(String args[]){

//create a Date object  
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("Date is : " + date);

//use getTime() method to retrieve milliseconds
System.out.println("Milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT : "
                  + date.getTime());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

**Solution using `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*:</sup>**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(toMillis("2012-07-11 10:55:21"));
    }

    public static long toMillis(String strDateTime) {
        // Replace the parameter, ZoneId.systemDefault() which returns JVM's default
        // timezone, as applicable e.g. to ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        
        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        
        return instant.toEpochMilli();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1342000521000
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)* from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sub>*For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sub>