# Is there any way to convert date String of any format to millisecond in java?

Tags: java

Is there any function or library which gets a date in milliseconds, given a `String`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436913/how-to-get-a-formatted-date-as-milliseconds) shows how to convert a  formatted `String` to a `Date` object, but is there any way to do this with an unformatted `String`?

Comment: The short answer would be, no.  The long answer would to look at something like [`DateUtils#parseDate`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) from [Apache Commons Lang API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) which allows you to pass a variable number of formats

Comment: This question does not make any sense. What amount of milliseconds would you like to get for "foo" and "foobar"; 10 & 200, or 42 and 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the task is impossible.  Here's an example:

```
01/04/2012
```

In the US, that means January 4th 2012.  In Australia, that mean 1st April 2012.

Without knowing where you are and what date formats conventionally mean, it is impossible to *accurately* map an arbitrary date-like string to a date time value that matches what the user actually meant.

And even if you *do* know about the relevant local conventions, users have a remarkable propensity to be oblivious to ambiguity.  Dealing with that may require deep domain knowledge (or mind reading skills!) to disambiguate the possible meanings.

---

When you think about it, this is why modern user interfaces typically use a date-picker widget of some kind when the user needs to enter a date / time

Answer (score 0):

first convert the string to `Date`. From there you can get time in milis using [Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) method

Comment: There in lies the problem.  If the format of the `String` is unknown, how to parse it

Comment: he told the string is a date string..  I thought it is in a formatted way.. :/

Comment: @StinePike "Thu, 20 Jun 2013 20:32:00 +0100" or "Wed, 19 Jun 2013" or anything else. I am getting date from `json`, there are different types of format.