# Android: How to get hour/min in milliseconds

Tags: android, time, timestamp

I am using timepicker. I can get date(calendar) in milliseconds but cant figure out with timepicker

with date i used:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(calendarView.getDate());
Date date = new Date(calendarView.getDate() / 1000L);
long timestamp = date.getTime()
//and this works
```

But i dont know with timePicker becouse i get two int's: hour, min.

Im just out of plays and dont know much more to try.. Could use the help

**SOLUTION:**

Dummy me just need to say the problem outloud.. Hopfully it will help someone else..

```
 long hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
 long min = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

 hour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hour);
 min = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min);
```

Comment: You may require this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735705/how-to-convert-date-format-to-milliseconds
)[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459656/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmisec-millisecond-format-in-java)

Comment: That totally depends. Are you trying to get the timestamp of an hour/minute combination that took place in the past? Or are you trying to get the timestamp in the future? Or are you trying to get both?

Comment: @SaravanarajaT well this dude is using Date but with timepicker there are no Date, get my drift.. it only gives me int but i want to pas that int into a value of millisecond..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimePicker` is design for 24hours of day, thus you cant get **date** within it just hours and minutes within the day.

as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) is saying:

```
A view for selecting the time of day, in either 24 hour or AM/PM mode.
```

I would recommend using [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) to enable you to get the date.

Comment: Yes I know about DatePicker but I wanted to go the other way. That is TimePicker and CalendarView. This makes my head hurts..

Comment: @SindriÞór you mean millisecond from a specified time?? can you give sample

Comment: Yes thats right.. I want milliseconds from past midnight.. For example: 5.5 hours is 19800000 millis.

Comment: @SindriÞór why not convert hours to millisecond??